# how can i stop the endless loop with pygame.time.set_timer

Tags: python, pygame

Want to change the color of the screen more often. It should be some kind of blinking.
This should happen when the button is pressed.
But the program runs in an endless loop.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
timer = pygame.time.Clock()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

bg_active_color = WHITE
screen.fill(WHITE) 
CHANGE_COLOR = pygame.USEREVENT + 1

pygame.time.set_timer(CHANGE_COLOR, 500)
counter = 0  
running = True
while running:   
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:                
                    if event.type == CHANGE_COLOR:
                        counter += 1                      
                        if counter < 4:
                            if bg_active_color == RED:
                                screen.fill(RED)
                                bg_active_color = WHITE
                            elif bg_active_color == WHITE:
                                screen.fill(WHITE)
                                bg_active_color = RED 
                        else:
                            pygame.time.set_timer(CHANGE_COLOR,0)
                            print("end")
                    
            
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:        
                        running = False
     
        pygame.display.update()

        timer.tick(30)
  
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not nest the events. You have to test the event type in an `if`-`elif`-`else` statement. Check if <kbd>LEFT</kbd> is pressed with the `KEYDOWN` event and `K_LEFT` key and start the timer. Do not call `fill` in the event loop. It is sufficient to change the `bg_active_color` variable:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
timer = pygame.time.Clock()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
bg_active_color = WHITE
CHANGE_COLOR = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
counter = 0  
running = True
while running:   
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:        
                running = False
        
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:    
                pygame.time.set_timer(CHANGE_COLOR, 500)
                counter = 0
        
        elif event.type == CHANGE_COLOR:                     
            if counter < 4:
                if bg_active_color == RED:
                    bg_active_color = WHITE
                elif bg_active_color == WHITE:
                    bg_active_color = RED 
            else:
                pygame.time.set_timer(CHANGE_COLOR,0)
                print("end")    
            counter += 1      
    
    screen.fill(bg_active_color) 

    pygame.display.update()
    timer.tick(30)
  
pygame.quit()
```